# java appengine automatic redirect to directory with slash

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In my local machine running eclipse with java. when i created a directory in my site named dir. It will automatically redirect to from 
http://localhost:8888/dir to http://localhost:8888/dir/

but when i deploy the app on appengine. then i tried the url
http://mysite.appspot.com/dir it will give an error. 
But http://mysite.appspot.com/dir/ will work.

how can i enable this automatic redirect?

Comment: Which framework ? Configuration ?

Comment: im using java appengine (java ee) has web.xml. the dir automatically redirects on localhost but when i deployed it on appengine it treats http://mysite.appspot.com/dir/ and  http://mysite.appspot.com/dir differently.  http://mysite.appspot.com/dir/ exists and  http://mysite.appspot.com/dir does not exists

Comment: It is weird that this technique works on how to fix my problem. but i am not sure why. xD https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/QTVjd9uDiXI

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small fix i found, not sure why it works but it works xD

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/QTVjd9uDiXI